# Syntax error JMeter DB2

Tags: sql, database, jdbc, jmeter, db2

Hy guys,

I'm trying to setup a DB2 (V11.1) stress test using Jmeter (3.1).

1. I've downloaded JMeter and the jdbc driver.
2. I've copied the jdbc driver into **JMETER_DR/lib/db2jcc4.jar**
3. I've created a Thread Group with 10 users
4. I've created the JDBC connection (disabling the Connection validation by Pool). Database URL: **jdbc:db2://10.40.2.157:50000/TEST** . JDBC Driver Class: **com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver**
5. I've created the JDBC Request: Query Type: **Select Statement**. Query: **select * from TEST.TESTTABLE;**

When I run the test plan I got the error:

> 1489682525237,5,DB2 JDBC select,42601 -104,"com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlSyntaxErrorException: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601, SQLERRMC=;;from TEST.TESTTABLE;END-OF-STATEMENT, DRIVER=4.16.53",DB2 Thread Group 1-1,text,false,,108,0,1,1,0,0,0

I've tested the same connection parameters and query using another Software (RazorSQL) and they are fine.

What it could be?

Answer (score 3):

You received the [illegal symbol error](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPEK_11.0.0/codes/src/tpc/n104.html).

Using semicolon after a single statement [may produce this error](http://forums.pentaho.com/showthread.php?164177-terminating-SQL-SELECT-statement-with-semicolon-causes-error).

Try to remove the semicolon `;`

Comment: Worked for me! Thanks, @george-rylkov !